# Edit 2 stat_hex_bin geoms separately ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I start by giving you my example code:

```
x <- runif(1000,0, 5)
y <- c(runif(500, 0, 2), runif(500, 3,5))
A <- data.frame("X"=x,"Y"=y[1:500])
B <- data.frame("X"=x,"Y"=y[501:1000])
ggplot() + 
  stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) +
  stat_bin_hex(data=B, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="red4", high="#ED1A3A")
```

It produces the following plot:
[image]

Now I want the lower hexagons to follow a different scale. Namely ranging from a dark green to a lighter green. How can I achieve that?

**Update:**
As you can see from the answers so far, I am asking myself whether there is a solution without using alpha scales. Also, using two plots with no margin or something similar is not an option for my specific application. Though they both are legitimate answers :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `stat_binhex()`?

Comment: Well both plot exactly the same. Not sure if there is a difference besides the name.

Comment: `stat_bin_hex` did not work for me. Perhaps, I have outdated version of `ggplot2`

Comment: I have `ggplot2_1.0.0`. Perhaps it's time to update )

Comment: The basic design in `ggplot` is one scale per aesthetic (see @hadley's opinion e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/lDvsd4yJ0AE)). Thus, work-arounds are necessary in a case like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to get two different fill scales in one plot you could alter the colours of the lower values, after the plot has been built. The basic idea is have two plots with the differing fill scales and then copy accross certain details from one plot to the other.

```
# Base plot
p <- ggplot() + 
  stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) +
  stat_bin_hex(data=B, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) 

# Produce two plots with different fill colours
p1 <- p + scale_fill_continuous(low="red4", high="#ED1A3A")
p2 <- p + scale_fill_continuous(low="darkgreen", high="lightgreen")

# Get fill colours for second plot and overwrite the corresponding 
# values in the first plot
g1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
g2 <- ggplot_build(p2)
g1$data[[1]][,"fill"] <- g2$data[[1]][,"fill"]

# You can draw this now but there is only one legend
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(g1))
```

To have two legends you can join the legends from the two plots together

```
# Bind the legends from the two plots together
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(g1)
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(g2)

g1$grobs[[grep("guide", g1$layout$name )]] <- 
  rbind(g1$grobs[[grep("guide", g1$layout$name )]], 
        g2$grobs[[grep("guide", g2$layout$name )]] )

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

Giving (from `set.seed(10)` prior to data generation)

[image]

Comment: Now thats even better. Though it's just a little frustrating that its not nativley possible to do this. Most of the times you end up modifying grobs. Good answer, I'll give the question some more days :)

Answer (score 2):

This should provide more or less what you want

```
 ggplot() + 
     stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y, alpha=..count..), bins=10,fill="green") +
     stat_bin_hex(data=B, aes(x=X, y=Y, alpha=..count..), bins=10,fill="red")
```

[image]

To avoid that the grey is disturbing due to the alpha one could underlay the plot with another white plot at the same location and darken the colours a bit, as suggested by the TO in the comments

```
 #just the red to show the impact due to scale_alpha
 ggplot() +scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.5,1))+ stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10,fill="white",show.legend = TRUE) +
+     stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y, alpha=..count..), bins=10,fill="red",show.legend = TRUE) +
+     stat_bin_hex(data=B, aes(x=X, y=Y, alpha=..count..), bins=10,fill="green", show.legend=TRUE)+guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry. I thought that this solution would come up. I already played around with it. But the problem for me is that the lightest hexagons arent visible enough. And if I use `scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.5,1))` the hexagons are not distuinguishable enough (for my purposes). So I wondered if there is a "no alpha" solution ;)

Comment: No worries. I just realise anyhow that there is another problem with it. The legends are a bit messed up. But as it is not what you want I leave it here, to avoid that others are trying it. ;)

Comment: actually I add an an ugly hack solution for that one in a second.

Comment: Your update looks promising to me ;) I will try it out. Thanks so far!

Comment: Just to give you a heads up: The tweak with plotting white (or even slightly grey) hexagons behind the colored ones is the best way so far. Anyway, I will leave this topic open for some more time to see if there is some more intput out there :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you want more options to play with the colours, just create two plots and remove all the space between the two plots when combined with `grid.arrange()`.

```
p1 <- ggplot() + stat_bin_hex(data=B, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="red4", high="#ED1A3A")  + xlab("") + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.5,1), "cm")) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2.5, 5.5)) 

p2 <-   ggplot() + stat_bin_hex(data=A, aes(x=X, y=Y), bins=10) + scale_fill_continuous(low="darkgreen", high="green") + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5,1,1,1), "cm")) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 2.5))

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Does not work for me. The data in my application are lower ad upper bounds of a confidence interval. So they need to be plotted both in the same graph :/